# Use JQ To Convert AWS Output To CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, export-to-csv, jq, aws-cli

I'm using JQ to parse the output of aws commands to CSV.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [(.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value), .InstanceId, .PrivateIpAddress, .LaunchTime, .State.Name, (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Owner")|.Value)] | @csv'
```

It does work. But the output is putting in extra quotes and slashes that aren't needed:

```
"\"USAWS1027-AWS\",\"i-0be1611d\",\"10.48.128.37\",\"2016-11-11T16:08:14.000Z\",\"stopped\""
"\"usamzdbd2153\",\"i-7e0d8b91\",\"10.1.233.153\",\"2015-02-19T16:57:57.000Z\",\"running\",\"tsenti\""
```

Why is it doing this? Is there any way I can direct the @csv option to jq to leave out the quotes and backslashes? And just leave the commas.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  A small snippet illustrating the input to jq would be helpful.

Comment: How does it get any more minimal than THAT???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, jq emits JSON, so you will probably want to use the -r option:

```
$ jq -n '"\"a\"" | [.] | @csv'  
"\"\"\"a\"\"\""

$ jq -nr '"\"a\"" | [.] | @csv'
"""a"""
```

Also, you might wish to strip the outermost double-quotation marks of any string that includes them.  Consider, for example:

```
$ jq -nr 'def s: gsub("^\"|\"$";""); "\"a\"" | [s] | @csv'
"a"
```

### The whole hog

If you want to eliminate the quotation marks around strings which do not contain commas, then consider:

```
echo '["usamzdbd2153","i-7e0d8b91","10.1.233.153","2015-02-19T16:57:57.000Z","running","tsenti"]' |
jq -r '
  def s: gsub("^\"|\"$";""); 
  def t: if test(",") then . else s end; 

  map(t) | join("\t") | gsub("\t";",")'
```

The output:

```
usamzdbd2153,i-7e0d8b91,10.1.233.153,2015-02-19T16:57:57.000Z,running,tsenti
```